# Handling on press event for every word in long text rendered on the screen in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity, touchablewithoutfeedback

1. I have a long text (for example, part of some book), and I need to render it on the screen but I need every word to handle touches. On touch I want to show the translation of this word. Is there any more efficient way to do this than wrapping every word in one of touchable components?
2. I want to be able to select a few words and see the translation on this words. Is there any way to do this in ReactNative if we wrap every word in touchable?

Comment: Stuck on a same situation, did you find the solution?